# How do subclass a widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

jQuery UI 1.8 added the ability to extend a widget using code like this:

```
$.widget("my.weirdbutton", $.ui.button, {
});
```

Now I can create a `weirdbutton` and it works a lot like a button:

```
$("#myButton").weirdbutton();
```

However, only weirdbutton events get fired. So if I have something like

```
$(".button").bind("buttoncreate", function() { 
    console.log("a button was created"); 
});
```

I will miss all the creation of weirdbuttons. This can be fixed by manually triggering the button events from the weirdbutton widget. Not great, but works.

A bigger problem is that code like this will not work:

```
$("#mybutton").weirdbutton();
$("#mybutton").button("option", "text", "My New Text");
```

The second line, rather than setting an option on the existing button, creates a new one. I don't know how to fix this.

So, is there a way to make a subclassed widget that follows the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for the `.bind` approach but replacing the initial `_create` method can be done using this approach:

```
$.widget("my.weirdbutton", $.ui.button, {
    _create: function() {
       $.ui.button.prototype._create.call(this);
       console.log("a button was created");
    }
});
```

Then if you do a (at document):

```
$(function() {
  $("#myButton").weirdbutton();      
});
```

you should get a `console.log`

Full code here: http://jsbin.com/icota4/11/edit

Comment: The problem is that `console.log` is called by the **user** of my plugin, not me. I don't know what they'll really want to do (logging is just an example), and I can't hard-code it into the widget code.

Comment: Thanks ant1j, I didn't knew how to call the original create-method of the superior class!

Comment: Do not forget to mark your question as "answered" if it's the case!